# Bloch functions and single-electron equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-functional-theory

The single electron equation is

$[\frac{\hat{\textbf{p}}^2}{2m_e}+v^{KS}(\textbf{r})]\psi_{n\textbf{k}}(\textbf{r})=\varepsilon_{n}(\textbf{k})\psi_{n\textbf{k}}(\textbf{r})~~~~~$ (1)

where $\hat{\textbf{p}}=-i\hbar\nabla_{\textbf{r}}$ is the electron momentum operator.

With the Bloch function $\psi_{n\textbf{k}}(\textbf{r})=u_{n\textbf{k}}(\textbf{r})e^{i\textbf{k}\cdot\textbf{r}}$, Eq. (1) becomes
$[\frac{\hat{\textbf{p}}^2}{2m_e}+v^{KS}(\textbf{r})]u_{n\textbf{k}}(\textbf{r})e^{i\textbf{k}\cdot\textbf{r}}=\varepsilon_{n}(\textbf{k})u_{n\textbf{k}}(\textbf{r})e^{i\textbf{k}\cdot\textbf{r}}~~~~~$ (2)

My question is that can I multiply Eq. (2) with $e^{-i\textbf{k}\cdot\textbf{r}}$ from the right side, and then Eq. (2) becomes
$[\frac{\hat{\textbf{p}}^2}{2m_e}+v^{KS}(\textbf{r})]u_{n\textbf{k}}(\textbf{r})=\varepsilon_{n}(\textbf{k})u_{n\textbf{k}}(\textbf{r})~~~~~$ (3)

I know this is wrong and leads to wrong results, but I do not know why?

Comment: It might help in answering your question by specifying what derived results might be incorrect.

Comment: Ha, sorry,  Eq. (3) is just the wrong result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The momentum operator $\hat{\textbf{p}} = - i \hbar \nabla_{\textbf{r}}$ acts also on the phase part of $\psi_{n\textbf{r}}(\textbf{r})$. By the chain rule it is 
\begin{equation}
\hat{\textbf{p}}^2\psi_{n\textbf{r}}(\textbf{r}) = - \hbar^2 \nabla_{\textbf{r}}^2 \left[u_{n\textbf{r}}(\textbf{r})e^{i\textbf{k}\cdot\textbf{r}}\right] = e^{i\textbf{k}\cdot\textbf{r}}\left[\hat{\textbf{p}} + \hbar\textbf{k} \right]^2 u_{n\textbf{r}}(\textbf{r}).
\end{equation}
This gives the proper equation for the Bloch functions,
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\frac{\left[\hat{\textbf{p}} + \hbar\textbf{k} \right]^2}{2m_e}+v^{KS}(\textbf{r})
\right\}
u_{n\textbf{k}}(\textbf{r})=\varepsilon_{n}(\textbf{k})u_{n\textbf{k}}(\textbf{r}).
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks. Looks like multiplying with $e^{-i\textbf{k}\cdot\textbf{r}}$, the Bloch function changes.